# How to open link in new page, then link back to the 1st page from the 2nd

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been asked to implement a web page which opens a new browser window when you click a link (Page 1). The new page (Page 2) will have a link which when clicked will open a new url in Page 1. This needs to work in IE 6, 8 and other current browsers ideally.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: The words "IE 6" and "other current browsers" can't be written onto the same phrase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To open the window:

```
window.open ("http://www.someurl.com/maypage","my window");
```

To change the url from the popup:

```
self.opener.location = "http://www.someurlcom/anotherpage";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Link in page 1
<a href="" onclick="window.open('someurl','page2'); return false;">open new window</a>

//Link in page 2
<a href="" onclick="opener.location.href='someurl'; return false;">show page in old window</a>
```